SLES 15 SP6 - Problem with Passbolt-Installation - ERROR: unable to bind listening socket for address '/run/php-fpm/www.sock': Permission denied (13)
we will install the Passbolt-Password-Manager on a SLES-System.
We use SLES 15 SP6. We are follow the Instrauction from this Installation-Guide:
https://www.passbolt.com/docs/hosting/install/ce/sles/
After the last Step:
sudo /usr/local/bin/passbolt-configure

we have set the Path to the Certificates an start the Process and End with this Message:
Setting up SSL...
    Do you want to setup a SSL certificate and enable HTTPS now?
    - manual: Prompts for the path of user uploaded ssl certificates and set up
nginx
    - auto:   Will issue a free SSL certificate with https://www.letsencrypt.org
 and set up nginx
    - none:   Do not setup HTTPS at all
================================================================================
1) manual
2) auto
3) none
#? 1
Enter the path to the SSL certificate: /root/cert.pem
Enter the path to the SSL privkey: /root/key.pem
=============================
Installing os dependencies...
=============================
====================================
Opening ports 80 and 443 on firewall
====================================
success
success
===================
Setting up nginx...
===================
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/nginx.service → /usr/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service.
/usr/local/bin/passbolt-configure: line 645: [: missing `]'
extension=gnupg.so
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/php-fpm.service → /usr/lib/systemd/system/php-fpm.service.
Job for php-fpm.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status php-fpm.service" and "journalctl -xeu php-fpm.service" for details.

When we type:
systemctl status php-fpm.service
and become this Message:
php-fpm.service - The PHP FastCGI Process Manager
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/php-fpm.service; enabled; preset: disabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2024-08-16 10:32:54 CEST; 5min ago
    Process: 7426 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/php-fpm --nodaemonize --fpm-config /etc/php8/fpm/php-fpm.conf (code=exited, status=78)
   Main PID: 7426 (code=exited, status=78)
        CPU: 153ms

Aug 16 10:32:54 LX-test0100 systemd[1]: Starting The PHP FastCGI Process Manager...
Aug 16 10:32:54 LX-test0100 php-fpm[7426]: [16-Aug-2024 10:32:54] ERROR: unable to bind listening socket for address '/run/php-fpm/www.sock': Permission denied (13)
Aug 16 10:32:54 LX-test0100 php-fpm[7426]: [16-Aug-2024 10:32:54] ERROR: FPM initialization failed
Aug 16 10:32:54 LX-test0100 systemd[1]: php-fpm.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=78/CONFIG
Aug 16 10:32:54 LX-test0100 systemd[1]: php-fpm.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 16 10:32:54 LX-test0100 systemd[1]: Failed to start The PHP FastCGI Process Manager.

Can you help me to install passbolt? What is the Reason?
